# Gstreamer unable to process a ts segment in a u8 vec from appsrc

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I have been trying to feed a u8 vec coming my application will read from a RabbitMQ into an appsrc to transcode it.

I am trying a simple pipeline like the following without decode to test it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=dip.ts ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=pp.ts
```

I wrote the following code to build the pipeline in rust. However I keep getting “Internal data stream error”.

```
fn create_pipeline() -> Result<gst::Pipeline, Error> {
    gst::init()?;

    let pipeline = gst::Pipeline::default();

    let video_info = &gst::Caps::builder("video/x-h264")
        .field("stream-format", &"byte-stream")
        .build();

    let appsrc = gst_app::AppSrc::builder()
        .caps(video_info)
        .format(gst::Format::Time)
        .build();

    // gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=dip.ts ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=pp.ts
    let tsdemux = gst::ElementFactory::make("tsdemux").build()?;
    let h264parse = gst::ElementFactory::make("h264parse").build()?;
    let mpegtsmux = gst::ElementFactory::make("mpegtsmux").build()?;
    let filesink = gst::ElementFactory::make("multifilesink").build()?;
    filesink.set_property("location", "%d.ts");
    filesink.set_property("post-messages", true);
    filesink.set_property_from_str("next-file", "discont");

    let video_sink_pad = h264parse.static_pad("sink").expect("could not get sink pad from h264parse");

    pipeline.add_many(&[appsrc.upcast_ref(), &tsdemux, h264parse.upcast_ref(), &mpegtsmux, &filesink])?;
    gst::Element::link_many(&[appsrc.upcast_ref(), &tsdemux])?;

    tsdemux.connect_pad_added(move |_src, src_pad| {
        let is_video = if src_pad.name().starts_with("video") {
            true
        } else {
            false
        };

        let connect_demux = || -> Result<(), Error> {
            src_pad.link(&video_sink_pad).expect("failed to link tsdemux.video->h264parse.sink");
            println!("linked tsdemux->h264parse");
            Ok(())
        };

        if is_video {
            match connect_demux() {
                Ok(_) => println!("tsdemux->h264 connected"),
                Err(e) => println!("could not connect tsdemux->h264parse e:{}", e),
            }
        }
    });


    gst::Element::link_many(&[&h264parse.upcast_ref(), &mpegtsmux, &filesink])?;

     appsrc.set_callbacks(
         gst_app::AppSrcCallbacks::builder()
             .need_data(move |appsrc, _| {
                 println!("getting the file");
                 let mut file = File::open("./dip.ts").unwrap();
                 let mut buffer = Vec::new();
                 match file.read_to_end(&mut buffer) {
                     Ok(_) => {
                         println!("finished reading bytes from file len={}", buffer.len());
                     }
                     Err(e) => {
                         println!("error reading file: {}", e);
                     }
                 };
                 let gst_buffer = gst::Buffer::from_slice(buffer);
                 println!("buffer size of teh generated gst_buffer={}", gst_buffer.size());
                 let _ = appsrc.push_buffer(gst_buffer);
             }).build(),
     );

    Ok(pipeline)

}
```

Is it because appsrc is not able to handle the buffer size? If so how do I divide it into chunks in a byte-stream?

Comment: It worked when I removed the caps from the appsrc. But I dont know why. If someone could explain that would be really helpful.

Comment: You have the wrong caps there. `tsdemux` will accept `video/mpegts` and delivers `video/x-h264` (if the stream includes such a format). So telling `tsdemux` to expect `video/x-h264` it will just refuse it as it does not handle such format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @florian. You were right. Changing the caps to video/mpegts and setting it to `systemstream` fixed the issue.

For the benefit of others here is the updated pipeline

```
fn create_pipeline() -> Result<gst::Pipeline, Error> {
    gst::init()?;

    let pipeline = gst::Pipeline::default();

    let video_info = &gst::Caps::builder("video/mpegts")
        .field("systemstream", true)
        .build();

    let appsrc = gst_app::AppSrc::builder()
        .caps(video_info)
        .format(gst::Format::Time)
        .build();

    // gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=dip.ts ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=pp.ts
    let tsdemux = gst::ElementFactory::make("tsdemux").build()?;
    let h264parse = gst::ElementFactory::make("h264parse").build()?;
    let mpegtsmux = gst::ElementFactory::make("mpegtsmux").build()?;
    let filesink = gst::ElementFactory::make("multifilesink").build()?;
    filesink.set_property("location", "%d.ts");
    filesink.set_property("post-messages", true);
    filesink.set_property_from_str("next-file", "discont");

    let video_sink_pad = h264parse.static_pad("sink").expect("could not get sink pad from h264parse");

    pipeline.add_many(&[appsrc.upcast_ref(), &tsdemux, h264parse.upcast_ref(), &mpegtsmux, &filesink])?;
    gst::Element::link_many(&[appsrc.upcast_ref(), &tsdemux])?;

    tsdemux.connect_pad_added(move |_src, src_pad| {
        let is_video = if src_pad.name().starts_with("video") {
            true
        } else {
            false
        };

        let connect_demux = || -> Result<(), Error> {
            src_pad.link(&video_sink_pad).expect("failed to link tsdemux.video->h264parse.sink");
            println!("linked tsdemux->h264parse");
            Ok(())
        };

        if is_video {
            match connect_demux() {
                Ok(_) => println!("tsdemux->h264 connected"),
                Err(e) => println!("could not connect tsdemux->h264parse e:{}", e),
            }
        }
    });


    gst::Element::link_many(&[&h264parse.upcast_ref(), &mpegtsmux, &filesink])?;

     appsrc.set_callbacks(
         gst_app::AppSrcCallbacks::builder()
             .need_data(move |appsrc, _| {
                 println!("getting the file");
                 let mut file = File::open("./dip.ts").unwrap();
                 let mut buffer = Vec::new();
                 match file.read_to_end(&mut buffer) {
                     Ok(_) => {
                         println!("finished reading bytes from file len={}", buffer.len());
                     }
                     Err(e) => {
                         println!("error reading file: {}", e);
                     }
                 };
                 let gst_buffer = gst::Buffer::from_slice(buffer);
                 println!("buffer size of teh generated gst_buffer={}", gst_buffer.size());
                 let _ = appsrc.push_buffer(gst_buffer);
             }).build(),
     );

    Ok(pipeline)

}
```